# How HTTP guarantees the chunked response can be received sequentially?

Tags: http

As titled.

How HTTP guarantees the chunked response can be received sequentially? Since there is no such ID on each of the chunked data groups to indicate the number of that group. Even though the backend server can send all the chunks sequentially, but due to the different routing of the Internet, the group client-side receives cannot be guaranteed sequentially, right? So, how HTTP solves an issue like that? I mean the wrong receiving order of the chunked groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying TCP protocol guarantees order. Any TCP-based protocol has this property.